# Delete list item in v-for directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

here I have a component which is showing one list.
Each element of the list can be deleted by clicking one button on list items side.

**Template**

```html
    <div
    v-for="(question, index) in questions"
    :key="index"
    class="q-gutter-md row items-start">
      <q-input
      v-model="question.question"
      label="Domanda"
      lazy-rules
      :name="'question' + index"
      :rules="[lengthValidation]"
      ></q-input>

      <q-select
      v-model="question.answerType"
      :options="answerTypesList"
      label="Tipo di risposta"
      :name="'answerType' + index"
      ></q-select>

      <q-btn
      flat
      class="q-ml-sm"
      color="negative"
      icon="cancel"
      :label="index"
      @click="removeQuestion(index)" />
    </div>
```

**Script**

```js
    removeQuestion (evt, index) {
      console.log(index)
      this.questions.splice(index, 1)
    }
```

**Result**
[image: Rendered list]

**Note:** The first row is not part of the list

When I "console.log" the "index" variable received from component, the value printed is "undefined", but as you can see, in part of the "delete" symbols, the index is correct.

How can I fix this?

Best regards

**Edit on 2020/04/26** script code modified since split method returns an array with the removed items and removes the item from the array:

**Before**

```
this.questions = this.questions.splice(index, 1)
```

**Current**

```
this.questions.splice(index, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only passed one value, the index, from the listener, so the method will receive that in its first argument, `evt`. Remove that argument to get the value in `index`:

```js
removeQuestion (index) {
  console.log(index)
  this.questions.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Or if you want to keep both arguments, make sure to pass the `$event` from the listener:

```js
@click="removeQuestion($event, index)"
```

You may have expected the event would pass automatically because when you attach a handler with no invocation, Vue will pass the event by default.  Such as:

```js
@click="removeQuestion"
```

This automatically passes one argument, the `$event`.  But if you specify your own invocation (i.e. `()`), that won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help, problem fixed! Can you just replace "this.questions = this.questions.splice(index, 1)" with "this.questions.splice(index, 1)" since that was wrong?